# How to separate lengthy string based on space position

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I having this value for example "**At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.**"

And i would like to separate the string every 20 character and do not want to break the words. wanted result as below

"**At w3schools.com**" (17 characaters)

"**you will learn how** " (18 characaters)

"**to make a website.** " (18 characaters)

"**We offer free** " (13 characaters)

"**tutorials in all web**" (20 characaters)

"**development**" (11 characaters)

"**technologies**" (12 characaters)

Code as below

```
Dim value as String = "At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies."

Dim array() = value.split(" ")
dim length      as integer = array.length


Dim eachLine    as integer = 0 
Dim newString   as string = ""

For counter as integer =0 to length -1

if(array(counter).length + eachLine < 20)

    newString += " " + array(counter)
    eachLine += array(counter).length
else
    newString   += " " + vbLf
    eachLine    = 0 
end if


Next
```

result i got as below

"**At w3schools.com you**"

"**learn how to make a** "

"**We offer free**"

"**in all web development**"

Comment: have you attempted something?

Comment: @KeithC I've tried used with split method and position , but the result is not desired

Comment: You should post examples of what you have tried, errors you have hit and what point you are having the confusion with

Comment: As suggested, we're not here to write your code for you but rather to help you fix code that you already have but isn't working.  If you have no code then posting here was premature.  If you have no idea how to start the code then you haven't really thought about the problem.  If you had to do this with pen and paper then you could, so you know EXACTLY what the code has to implement.  Write down the steps that you would follow to do it manually and that's your algorithm.  Now you can write code to implement that algorithm rather than plucking it out of the air.

Comment: @jmcilhinney edit with the code i've attempted and result for ur reference

Comment: And what is the algorithm that you're trying to implement?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use `Split` at all, although it can be done. I would tend to use `LastIndexOf` and `Substring`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney likes I said and code above shown, i did tried to separate the words by using "space" and calculate the words till each line 20 characters, but the results is not desired. Hence, posting here to look for better solution/algorithm.

Comment: That's not an algorithm. If you don't know what the code is supposed to do before writing it then is it any wonder it doesn't do what you want? Think of an algorithm as a recipe. Would your description of what you're trying to achieve be considered even close to acceptable as a recipe? Of course not! It's ridiculously vague. Be SPECIFIC. Each step in your algorithm should correspond to probably three lines of code at the absolute most.  If you can't get it down to that level of specificity then you're just not trying.

Comment: @jmcilhinney be [nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) :) look at their reputation